# How could I make the make form open with custom link in jqGrid.?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I would like to use the supplied link to open an edit form. How would i start in doing and modifying that? What actions do I have to take to make this work? really need this.There has to be a simple way to call that action?
[image: Edit Project]

So I tried to do do a "double click" row but it would be disabled everytime I inserted the "datepicker" as per below. So instead, right now Im trying to open the form edtor with the "edit Project" link above?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ 
      $("#list").jqGrid({
        url:'request.php',
        datatype: 'xml',
        mtype: 'GET',
        height: 350,
        colNames:['id','Project', 'Assigned To','Assign Date','Check Date','Due Date','Attachments'],
        colModel :[ 
          {name:'id', index:'id', width:20}, 
          {name:'name', index:'name', width:200, align:'left',editable:true, editoptions:{
                size:70} }, 
          {name:'id_continent', index:'id_continent', width:80, align:'right',editable:true,edittype:'select', 
          editoptions:{value: "Henry:Henry; Ramon:Ramon; Paul:Paul" }  }, 

          {name:'lastvisit', index:'lastvisit', width:70, align:'right',formatter: 'date',srcformat:'yyyy-mm-dd',newformat: 'm-d-Y',editable:true, edittype: 'text', }, 
          {name:'cdate', index:'cdate', width:80, align:'right',formatter: 'date',srcformat:'yyyy-mm-dd',newformat: 'm-d-Y',editable:true, edittype: 'text',editoptions: {
                  size: 12,
                  maxlengh: 12,
                  dataInit: function (element) {
                      $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy' }
                                )
                  }
              },
              editrules: {
                  date: true
              }

          },
          {name:'ddate', index:'ddate', width:80, align:'right',formatter: 'date',srcformat:'yyyy-mm-dd',newformat: 'm-d-Y',date:'true',editable:true, edittype: 'text',}, 
          {name:'email', index:'email', width:80,align:'center',sortable:false} 
        ],
        pager: '#pager',
        rowNum:20,
        rowList:[20,40,80],
        sortname: 'id',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: 'Pending Assignements',

        //ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {

    //$(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid, {height:300,width:450,reloadAfterSubmit:false,closeAfterEdit:true,closeOnEscape:true});

    //}

        }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true,del: true,add:false  },
                 {},//Options for the Edit Dialog
                 {},//Options for the Add Dialog
                 {}//Options for Delete

                 ),

    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('delGridRow', row_id_s, options );}); 



    </script>
```

Comment: You mean the "Files" Hyperlink in your screenshot?

Comment: no i mean the "edit project". Its a commmon html tag link. What do i need to make it point to the Form Edit and open it? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused at what you mean? Are you adding in the built in edit button on every line? a custom button? I personally have a edit form dialog in my project that opens on double clicking on a row, so I just need to know what you are trying to hook to to give you an example.

Comment: It is a custom button on the top of the page titled " Edit Project". How would you tell the script that once you click on it to open the edit form dialogue for the selected row?

Comment: Wait open on double click? I tried that too but for some reason it would conflict with the  datepicker code that I had added in 3 lines. It would make the double click inactive

Comment: If you could help me with my original question that would be awesome. BUt if you could also shine some light on making the double click the row to edit while having 3 instances of datepicker would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Edit button click event:

```
$('#ButtonName').click(function () { editSelectedRow(); });
```

Custom Function:

```
function editSelectedRow() {
    //set the grid so we don't have to search the DOM multiple times
    var grid = $('#gridName');

    //ensure a row is selected
    var selectedRow = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    if (selectedRow) {
        idRowData = grid.jqGrid('getRowData', selectedRow)
        grid.jqGrid('editGridRow', 'new', { closeAfterEdit: true, closeAfterSubmit: true, closeAfterAdd: true, recreateForm: true,
                viewPagerButtons: false,
                editData: { ExtraKeyName: ExtraKeyValue },
                afterShowForm: function (formid) {
                }, //afterShowForm
                afterComplete: function (response) {
                 } //afterComplete
            }); //$this.jqGrid('editGridRow
    }
    else {

        alert("Please select a row);
    } //else 
}
```

Comment: Maybe i added it incorrectly. It doesn't work. i commented out .navgrid line and added the above under it. It just stopped the grid from generating. I'm a noob so please explain i more detail please.

Comment: @user2288431 This button event binding, and custom function would be declared outside your jqGrid setup, if there is an error past that there must be an error in your Javascript and you should be able to see where your error is in your IDE or with something like Firebug

Comment: Ok i declared it out side and I get a "unterminated string literal" warning @ jquery 1.90.min.js (line 2, col 14) },set:function(e,n,r){return st.nodeName(e,"input")?(e.defaultValue=n,t):Ct&&Ct.set(e,n,r)}}),Ht||(Ct=st.valHooks.button={get:function(e,n){var r=e.getAttributeNode(n);return r&&("id"===n||"name"===n||"coords"===n?""!==r.value:r.specified)?r.value:t},set:function(e,n,r)... etc is long.

Comment: @user2288431 You have an error in your javascript some wheres I would guess, prune back what you have till it works and then slowly add back till it breaks again, verifying that you have properly formatted javascript.

Comment: I found the problem. 
        alert("Please select a row);
    } //else--------the end quote after row. But still not working. I'm i suppose to use the "id" of the button  or the "name"?

Comment: @user2288431 In the jquery selector? It would be the id in the format of $('#ID_Of_Element'), not to be rude, but this is some basic javascript, jQuery stuff.

Comment: @user2288431 Again not to be rude, but I can't troubleshoot basic stuff for you with that information, nor is this the place for it.  If you have questions about basic Javascript or JQuery, please search on those topics, or post a question in those areas.  I could be wrong but Stackoverflow is about getting a point in the right direction, with some code help (if your lucky) and it's still up to you to finish.

Comment: understood. i tried it and it acts! The warning pops up when their isn't a row selected but does not act when their is a row selected. Gives a warning "ReferenceError: ExtraKeyValue is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

editData: { ExtraKeyName: ExtraKeyValue },

Comment: @user2288431 Remove the ` ExtraKeyName: ExtraKeyValue` as that is examples of how to pass up extra data to the controller.